# Regex prioritized match

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regular expression where I match in words:

1. The first letter
2. If the word has more than two letters: the first consonant OR if there is no consonant, the first vowel
3. If the word has more than one letter: the last letter

I am using the expression:

```
\s*([a-zA-Z])[eyuioaEYUIOA]*([qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnmQWRTPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]?)[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])[-\?\.,\s+]
```

but I do not understand how to implement the OR function: In the text below I fail do match "Now", "not" correctly. My matches are N_w, n_t but they should be Now, not

*Now this is not the end. It is not even the beginning of the end. But it is, perhaps, the end of the beginning.*

How should I implement the prioritized OR function?

Example:

```
I am now this is the even beginning perhaps match keen vlk
```

Desired matches

```
I am now ths is the evn bgg prs mth ken vlk
```

Comment: some examples for matched and unmatched strings would be better.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Please edit your post to explain better (in particular the rule n°3) and give the expected results for all the sentence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does `beginning` become `bgg` and not `bgnnng`, for example?

Comment: Ok, it's more clear now. What language do you use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this regular expression I think you have to use a conditionnal statement, one way to do it is : `\s*([a-zA-Z])(?(?=\S*?[qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnmQWRTPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]\S)(?:\S*?)([qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnmQWRTPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM])|([eyuioaEYUIOA]))?[a-zA-Z]*?([a-zA-Z])[-\?\.,\s+]` in this expression, the first group is the first letter, the second one is the first consonnant if there is one and it's not a 2 word letter, the third one is the first vowel and the fourth one is the last letter. The second and third ones can be empty.

You can check it on http://regex101.com/r/yQ1aR3/2.